# Playing media multiple times when play button clicks in notification bar

Tags: android, android-service, android-mediaplayer, android-notifications

I created a application which plays a music in service.. The service runs quite well and the music is played as expected. The problem i face is when i click the play button again in notification before the audio stops the music plays again in backgrounds which in turns the audio is playing parallel. If `mediaplayer.isPlaying` condition doesn't seems working!
My Code is

```
public class MediaPlayerService extends Service implements MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener {
    Notification status;
    private final String LOG_TAG = "NotificationService";
    private MediaPlayer mediaPlayer;;
    private MediaSessionManager mManager;
    private MediaSession mSession;
    private MediaController mController;
    /** indicates how to behave if the service is killed */
    int mStartMode;

    /** interface for clients that bind */
    IBinder mBinder;

    /** indicates whether onRebind should be used */
    boolean mAllowRebind;

    /** Called when the service is being created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
        mediaPlayer.reset();
        mediaPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(this);
    }
    @Nullable
    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        AssetFileDescriptor afd = null;
        try {
            afd = getAssets().openFd("mySound.mp3");
            mediaPlayer.setDataSource(afd.getFileDescriptor(),afd.getStartOffset(),afd.getLength());
            mediaPlayer.prepare();
            if(!mediaPlayer.isPlaying()) {
                Toast.makeText(this, "Not Playing", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                mediaPlayer.start();
            }
            else{
                Toast.makeText(this, "Playing", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                mediaPlayer.pause();
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        if (intent.getAction().equals(Constants.ACTION.STARTFOREGROUND_ACTION)) {
            showNotification();
            Toast.makeText(this, "Service Started", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        } else if (intent.getAction().equals(Constants.ACTION.PREV_ACTION)) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Clicked Previous", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            Log.i(LOG_TAG, "Clicked Previous");
        } else if (intent.getAction().equals(Constants.ACTION.PLAY_ACTION)) {
            if(mediaPlayer.isPlaying()) {
                Toast.makeText(this, "Playing", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            else{
                Toast.makeText(this, "Not Playing", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }
            Log.i(LOG_TAG, "Clicked Play");
        } else if (intent.getAction().equals(Constants.ACTION.NEXT_ACTION)) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Clicked Next", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            Log.i(LOG_TAG, "Clicked Next");
        } else if (intent.getAction().equals(
                Constants.ACTION.STOPFOREGROUND_ACTION)) {
            if(mediaPlayer.isPlaying()) {
                mediaPlayer.stop();
            }
            stopForeground(true);
            stopSelf();
        }
        return START_STICKY;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
        showNotificationClose();
        Toast.makeText(this, "OVER", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
    /** A client is binding to the service with bindService() */
    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return mBinder;
    }

    /** Called when all clients have unbound with unbindService() */
    @Override
    public boolean onUnbind(Intent intent) {
        return mAllowRebind;
    }

    /** Called when a client is binding to the service with bindService()*/
    @Override
    public void onRebind(Intent intent) {

    }

    /** Called when The service is no longer used and is being destroyed */
    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {

    }
    private void showNotification() {
// Using RemoteViews to bind custom layouts into Notification
        RemoteViews views = new RemoteViews(getPackageName(),
                R.layout.status_bar);
        RemoteViews bigViews = new RemoteViews(getPackageName(),
                R.layout.status_bar_expanded);

// showing default album image
        views.setViewVisibility(R.id.status_bar_icon, View.VISIBLE);
        views.setViewVisibility(R.id.status_bar_album_art, View.GONE);
        bigViews.setImageViewBitmap(R.id.status_bar_album_art,
                Constants.getDefaultAlbumArt(this));

        Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(this, myHome.class);
        notificationIntent.setAction(Constants.ACTION.MAIN_ACTION);
        notificationIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK
                | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0,
                notificationIntent, 0);

        Intent previousIntent = new Intent(this, MediaPlayerService.class);
        previousIntent.setAction(Constants.ACTION.PREV_ACTION);
        PendingIntent ppreviousIntent = PendingIntent.getService(this, 0,
                previousIntent, 0);

        Intent playIntent = new Intent(this, MediaPlayerService.class);
        playIntent.setAction(Constants.ACTION.PLAY_ACTION);
        PendingIntent pplayIntent = PendingIntent.getService(this, 0,
                playIntent, 0);

        Intent nextIntent = new Intent(this, MediaPlayerService.class);
        nextIntent.setAction(Constants.ACTION.NEXT_ACTION);
        PendingIntent pnextIntent = PendingIntent.getService(this, 0,
                nextIntent, 0);

        Intent closeIntent = new Intent(this, MediaPlayerService.class);
        closeIntent.setAction(Constants.ACTION.STOPFOREGROUND_ACTION);
        PendingIntent pcloseIntent = PendingIntent.getService(this, 0,
                closeIntent, 0);

        views.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.status_bar_play, pplayIntent);
        bigViews.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.status_bar_play, pplayIntent);

        views.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.status_bar_next, pnextIntent);
        bigViews.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.status_bar_next, pnextIntent);

        views.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.status_bar_prev, ppreviousIntent);
        bigViews.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.status_bar_prev, ppreviousIntent);

        views.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.status_bar_collapse, pcloseIntent);
        bigViews.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.status_bar_collapse, pcloseIntent);

        views.setImageViewResource(R.id.status_bar_play,
                R.drawable.apollo_holo_dark_pause);
        bigViews.setImageViewResource(R.id.status_bar_play,
                R.drawable.apollo_holo_dark_pause);

        views.setTextViewText(R.id.status_bar_track_name, "Cheap Thrills");
        bigViews.setTextViewText(R.id.status_bar_track_name, "Cheap Thrills");

        views.setTextViewText(R.id.status_bar_artist_name, "Sia");
        bigViews.setTextViewText(R.id.status_bar_artist_name, "Sia");

        bigViews.setTextViewText(R.id.status_bar_album_name, "Cheap Thrills");

        status = new Notification.Builder(this).build();
        status.contentView = views;
        status.bigContentView = bigViews;
        status.flags = Notification.FLAG_ONGOING_EVENT;
        status.icon = R.drawable.icon;
        status.contentIntent = pendingIntent;
        startForeground(Constants.NOTIFICATION_ID.FOREGROUND_SERVICE, status);
    }

    private void showNotificationClose() {
// Using RemoteViews to bind custom layouts into Notification
        RemoteViews views = new RemoteViews(getPackageName(),
                R.layout.status_bar);
        RemoteViews bigViews = new RemoteViews(getPackageName(),
                R.layout.status_bar_expanded);

// showing default album image
        views.setViewVisibility(R.id.status_bar_icon, View.VISIBLE);
        views.setViewVisibility(R.id.status_bar_album_art, View.GONE);
        bigViews.setImageViewBitmap(R.id.status_bar_album_art,
                Constants.getDefaultAlbumArt(this));

        Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(this, myHome.class);
        notificationIntent.setAction(Constants.ACTION.MAIN_ACTION);
        notificationIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK
                | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0,
                notificationIntent, 0);

        Intent previousIntent = new Intent(this, MediaPlayerService.class);
        previousIntent.setAction(Constants.ACTION.PREV_ACTION);
        PendingIntent ppreviousIntent = PendingIntent.getService(this, 0,
                previousIntent, 0);

        Intent playIntent = new Intent(this, MediaPlayerService.class);
        playIntent.setAction(Constants.ACTION.PLAY_ACTION);
        PendingIntent pplayIntent = PendingIntent.getService(this, 0,
                playIntent, 0);

        Intent nextIntent = new Intent(this, MediaPlayerService.class);
        nextIntent.setAction(Constants.ACTION.NEXT_ACTION);
        PendingIntent pnextIntent = PendingIntent.getService(this, 0,
                nextIntent, 0);

        Intent closeIntent = new Intent(this, MediaPlayerService.class);
        closeIntent.setAction(Constants.ACTION.STOPFOREGROUND_ACTION);
        PendingIntent pcloseIntent = PendingIntent.getService(this, 0,
                closeIntent, 0);

        views.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.status_bar_play, pplayIntent);
        bigViews.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.status_bar_play, pplayIntent);

        views.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.status_bar_next, pnextIntent);
        bigViews.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.status_bar_next, pnextIntent);

        views.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.status_bar_prev, ppreviousIntent);
        bigViews.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.status_bar_prev, ppreviousIntent);

        views.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.status_bar_collapse, pcloseIntent);
        bigViews.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.status_bar_collapse, pcloseIntent);

        views.setImageViewResource(R.id.status_bar_play,
                R.drawable.apollo_holo_dark_play);
        bigViews.setImageViewResource(R.id.status_bar_play,
                R.drawable.apollo_holo_dark_play);

        views.setTextViewText(R.id.status_bar_track_name, "Cheap Thrills");
        bigViews.setTextViewText(R.id.status_bar_track_name, "Cheap Thrills");

        views.setTextViewText(R.id.status_bar_artist_name, "Sia");
        bigViews.setTextViewText(R.id.status_bar_artist_name, "Sia");

        bigViews.setTextViewText(R.id.status_bar_album_name, "Cheap Thrills");

        status = new Notification.Builder(this).build();
        status.contentView = views;
        status.bigContentView = bigViews;
        status.flags = Notification.FLAG_ONGOING_EVENT;
        status.icon = R.drawable.icon;
        status.contentIntent = pendingIntent;
        startForeground(Constants.NOTIFICATION_ID.FOREGROUND_SERVICE, status);
    }

}
```

Comment: check if it is playing or not on `onResume()`

Comment: @hrskrs I presses play button from notification. Then will it call the onResume function?? Also will a service have onResume function?

Answer (score 1):

When you create an Intent in your Notification a new service instance is created and hence a new mediaplayer instance and so on.. due to which song starts playing again.

You should bind the service if you wish to have a connection with it.

Comment: I solved the problem.. Just initialised mediaplayer and source in onCreate and plays by checking in respective actions